# Get the name of a DependencyProperty in a Windows Store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties

Let's say I have a `DependencyProperty`, and I would like to have its string name.  In the .NET Framework, I could just access the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.name.aspx) property of the DependencyProperty.  For example, I could do:

```
string propertyName = FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty.Name;
```

The Windows Store version of `DependencyProperty` [doesn't seem to have a `Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242362).

What is a good method to obtain the name?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested this, but perhaps

```
myDependencyProperty.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Name
```

or

```
myDependencyProperty.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("name")
```